# How to hash a ring buffer of integers?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash

I am using Python. I have some lists containing integers, but they are actually ring buffers.

The following are rules by examples:

- We do not add new elements or modify any elements. These rings are immutable.
- No repetitive elements in a ring.
- If two lists have different lengths, they are not the same ring.
- Between two lists of the same length, if one list, after arbitrary times of **ring shift** or **reversion**, can be identical to the other, the two rings are equal. For example, `[1, 7, 9, 2, 5]` and `[7, 9, 2, 5, 1]`(ring shifted) are equal, `[1, 7, 9, 2, 5]` and `[1, 5, 2, 9, 7]`(ring shifted and reversed) are equal, but `[1, 7, 9, 2, 5]` and `[7, 1, 9, 2, 5]` are not equal.

I want to quickly identify whether two rings are equal.

One method is to compare their elements, another method is to find a good hashing method. I tried shifting two lists to their normal state and compare if their elements are identical (or identical after reversed), but it's too slow.

I think hashing is a better choice. So what hashing method is good for this kind of ring buffers?

The following is what I currently have:

```
import random
from time import perf_counter
from typing import List, Tuple

class Ring:
    def __init__(self, ids:List[int]) -> None:
        self.ids = ids

    def get_shifted(self, n:int) -> 'Ring':
        result_list = self.ids.copy()
        for i in range(n):
            head = result_list[0]
            result_list.remove(head)
            result_list.append(head)
        return Ring(result_list)
    
    def get_normalized(self) -> 'Ring':
        min_i = self.ids.index(min(self.ids))
        shifted = self.get_shifted(min_i)
        return shifted
    
    def get_reversed(self) -> 'Ring':
        result_list = self.ids.copy()
        result_list.reverse()
        return Ring(result_list)

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Ring') -> bool:
        if len(self.ids) != len(other.ids):
            return False
        normalized1 = tuple(self.get_normalized().ids)
        normalized2 = tuple(self.get_reversed().get_normalized().ids)
        normalized_other = tuple(other.get_normalized().ids)
        return normalized1 == normalized_other or normalized2 == normalized_other
    
    @staticmethod
    def Random() -> 'Ring':
        unduplicated = set()
        while len(unduplicated) < ring_capacity:
            unduplicated.add(random.randint(0, 20))
        return Ring(list(unduplicated))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed(1)
    ring_capacity = 5
    num_rings = 2000

    ring_set = []
    random_rings = [Ring.Random() for _ in range(num_rings)]

    start = perf_counter()
    for ring in random_rings:
        if ring not in ring_set:
            ring_set.append(ring)
    end = perf_counter()

    print(end - start)
    print(f'{len(ring_set)} out of {num_rings} unduplicated rings')
```

Comment: @trincot Good point. I'll make a simple version.

Comment: Can there be duplicate elements or are they always unique as in your examples?

Comment: *"I want to quickly identify whether two rings are equal"* - Is that actually what you want? You only have *two*? Or do you have *many* and want to find equal ones or something like that? And how long are they and how large can the elements be?

Comment: What you've described here is not a ring buffer.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have to compare them over and over again. So I want to calculate hash. Now I can make normalized rings but only in one direction. I don't know how to include reversion.

Comment: @KellyBundy No duplication in one ring.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have many rings, and I need to compare them pair-wise.

Comment: Your code to find the lexicographically smallest is Theta(n^2).

Comment: If there's no repeated elements in the ring, you can find the lexicographically smallest variant in O(n) time in a simple way that doesn't involve storing all rotations and reflections -- it starts with the smallest element in the array and then goes left or right depending which element is smaller.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks. So what you are saying is to find the smallest element as head, and then find the smaller neighber of the head as the second element. This is good.

Comment: Your `Random()` method is bad. Using a `set` somewhat sorts.

Comment: *"and I need to compare them pair-wise"* - Do you really? Why? In your sample code, you're just doing that to deduplicate the rings.

Comment: Without the `seed` call, you get around 1910 different Rings every time. If the `Random()` method instead does `return Ring(random.sample(range(21), ring_capacity))`, then you get around 1990 instead. Shows the sorting effect of your `set` in that method.

Comment: @KellyBundy In my example it's comparing with all existing ones, I think it's nearly pair-wise (maybe, because I keep making mistakes). Thanks very much for your new random method.

Comment: Yes, that's nearly pairwise. But you probably shouldn't be doing that and use a set instead (as we've seen in my answer), so that each ring only gets equality-compared to ring(s) with the same hash. At least in the application of your benchmark, which is really not about pairwise comparing of the 2000 rings but about deduplicating the 2000 rings. So if deduplicating rings is your actual task, then it's not about comparing (almost) all pairs.

Comment: Yes, I have got hash of normalized tuples, so now I will use a set instead.

Comment: Correction of my earlier comment: your set in `Random()` doesn't just *somewhat* sort. Your values are dense enough that It *sorts*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's faster and simpler to just compute a normalized form at construction:

```
class Ring:
    def __init__(self, ids:List[int]) -> None:
        self.ids = ids
        i = ids.index(min(ids))
        self.normed = min(
            ids[i:] + ids[:i],
            ids[i::-1] + ids[:i:-1]
        )

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Ring') -> bool:
        return self.normed == other.normed
```

Output with yours:

```
15.41106627508998
1896 out of 2000 unduplicated rings
```

Output with mine:

```
0.38525977171957493
1896 out of 2000 unduplicated rings
```

Output with the below ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVTBbpwwEL30Ur5ibhh1F5FIlSqUjfoBVQ9Rb6uV5eIhWAKb2kbtKsqX9JJL-1H9mnpsloU2XMDz3sy8eTb--Xs8-87ol5dfk2_3H_68eauG0VgPVmhphqy1ZgCvBoQ5PqJteWMm7dHO6HlU-vGCf1LO7-DLNPaYZU0vnIOHANcZhEdiC5wrrTznzGHf7kBJV1POUWl_KmB_D5-NxkSnh1hlIMGBqEtYpXWptMQfbFCahVVRbNO0sQPKwCR8gWK6dEdVn-Bd_KrVafcKXO9vrgxaLJx_-nTCdaELvZinydmqfRC1mh2_LZMb36GtISd78jj5V2P66-QW_WT1dpJDyprXkboqTgLm8sXrdYiR5Hx0XnjVDBi2Xy41HuKus6gmCbvWmbQMs6lG-OipQ8-uPnzvVI_Qo2ZrWgF3YEMV3ohRNMqf643Na2oppGTp0JX0CseBVTu4rVabOk9Culgfzsy2V-JlmSIrtBiQczIs53wQSnM-jzL3cIiS3aScjcQw2vsY1dPACaGjd1tVVbZKX4AjiSkX21pjgYPSRHtEtpQoTik7mB7-kcPmL2IrEcHU2dp1n0RALf_PjMhoyS3C96lDsQq3-RNty6V88Qxm8mBaeFrUPW_3NsbyIt0I88VwuSD-Ag)):

```
0.0007639830000698566
1896 out of 2000 unduplicated rings
```

(Hmm, I just realized that by moving the normalization into construction, I moved it out of the timing. But if I include the `random_rings = [Ring.Random() for _ in range(num_rings)]` in the timing, the whole thing still only takes ~0.03 seconds.)

The last is modifying your *using* code to make your `ring_set` an actual set instead of a misnamed list:

```
    start = perf_counter()
    ring_set = set(random_rings)
    end = perf_counter()
```

With the `Ring` class providing meaningful hashes:

```
class Ring:
    def __init__(self, ids:List[int]) -> None:
        self.ids = ids
        i = ids.index(min(ids))
        self.normed = min(
            ids[i:] + ids[:i],
            ids[i::-1] + ids[:i:-1]
        )
        self.hash = hash(tuple(self.normed))

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Ring') -> bool:
        return self.normed == other.normed
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash
```

Comment: This solution is excellent. Yes, I don't need to keep the original list.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of coming up with a special hash that would provide the same hash code for equivalent lists, it is probably simpler to convert each ring to a canonical form.

Of all the possible shifts/reversions, for example, you can select the one that is lexically smallest.

After conversion to canonical form, equivalent rings are identical, so if you want to hash, then you can use whatever hash you want, and if you need to compare, you can just do a simple linear comparison.

Comment: Didn't they say they already tried this and it's too slow?

Comment: Maybe, but I think they would have been talking about something to do during comparison, whereas I suggest pre-calculating canonical forms, either temporarily before hashing, or in storage.

Comment: Yes, but you need Booth's algorithm or similar to find the lexically smallest one, otherwise there's obvious bad inputs which give O(N^2) runtime (for example, when the input string consists of a repeated short string). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation

Comment: @MattTimmermans Hmm, ok, but it's not clear from your answer that you suggest "pre-calculating". (And we really need more context from them than *"want to quickly identify whether two rings are equal"*).

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right that we could use more context, and that's why my answer is vague...  but I have personally had this kind of requirement several times over the years, and I think I remember that a canonical form was the best answer in all of those cases, so I think there's a good chance that it will be the best answer for whatever the OPs requirements are.

Comment: @PaulHankin  Not sure how Booth's algorithm applies, but I'm sure the lexically smallest rotation can be found in linear time, if the lists are long enough for that to matter.

Comment: The question includes the condition that the elements "aren't repetitive" which I assume means the elements are unique. Then it's very easy to canonicalize...

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that.  If they're unique then it's very easy.

Comment: Booth's algorithm is the way to get linear time if there's repeated elements (it's a surprisingly difficult problem to find the lex smallest rotation in linear time in general...).

Comment: Thank you everyone. What I needed to do is like the `ring_set` in the example code: every time when I have a new ring, I have to compare it with all existing rings. It's true that I've no idea which performs better. I am just imagining hashing may be better. I will check the algorithms you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, if you're going to make a `ring_set`, then you should store them in canonical form.  In Python, it will probably be most efficient to canonicalize, then convert to string, and use the built-in set.

Comment: @PaulHankin  I had to look that one up.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad so any recommendation will probably be rather vague, too. It sounds like you are processing gigantic amounts of data - otherwise comparison would certainly be faster than hashing.
You cannot use the standard cryptographic hash functions as they are not location independent. Rather look for location preserving hash functions (LP Hashes) like the Nilsimsa Hash. The idea is to have similar input create similar output where similar here means, that the starting point is arbitrary and still the set would create the same hash. Btw., a very simple hash for finding candidates would be the conventional (SAE J1708) checksum.